# ssh to remote host using sshpass and fetch results using java

Tags: java, linux, sshpass

I'm trying to run some commands on a remote machine and capture the result using Java. I have a shell script called test.sh which has following commands:

```
sshpass -p 'password' ssh root@host.com echo hostname
```

I'm running it using below java code:

```
public void runCommand() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
    boolean isWindows = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().startsWith("windows");
    if (isWindows) {
        builder.command("cmd.exe", "/c", "dir");
    } else {
        builder.command("sh", "-c", "sh test.sh");
    }
    builder.directory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
    Process process;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        process = builder.start();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
        }
        String output = stringBuilder.toString();
        System.out.println(output);
    } finally

    {
        if (reader != null)
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
    }
}
```

The command executes but I'm not getting anything in the output. If I use simple commands like echo, hostname then I'm able to get the result in output. I know of JSch which can solve the problem, but I can't use it.

Comment: Maybe yiu get some exception and do not log them?

Comment: @telex the script runs without any issues if i run it from terminal

Comment: It doesn't answer my question.

Comment: how do i see if there is any exception?

Comment: Look in your code where `IOException` is caught and check that it logged properly. Then look at logs.

Comment: Or you can just debug your code.

Comment: I'm getting exit code 127 for process object meaning "command not found".

Comment: For now you completely ignore error output from your command. You might obtain more details about the error by using [`ProcessBuilder.redirectErrorStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream--). Probably `sshpass` not installed, or installed but not in `$PATH` for your java process.

Comment: @Hugues M thanks, it was a problem related to path indeed. I fixed it by using absolute path of sshpass.

Comment: Posted answer 'cause I don't like seeing unanswered questions resolved in comments :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When starting a `Process` in Java, you *must* consume both stdout and stderr to [avoid blocking](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html), and you *should* log or control both (avoid consume-to-discard). There are now easier solutions than what the linked article mentions, using `ProcessBuilder`.

In this instance you completely ignore error output from your command. You said your process exits with status code 127, so it probably prints on stderr so you will obtain more details about the error by using `ProcessBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true)`.

Probably sshpass not installed, or installed but not in `$PATH` for your java process.